# convert readable GUID to IFC-GUID (22 character length string) - Python

Tags: python-3.x, guid, ifc

Currently I get a string for the GUID (readable) but I need the GUID as a fixed 22 character length string.

What i get:

'{0a820503-7dbf-4386-a8ec-9a312d6a81c2}'

What i need:

0AWWK3VRz3XgZicZ4jQe72

How can I convert the received string to get the GUID needed for IFC?

https://technical.buildingsmart.org/resources/ifcimplementationguidance/ifc-guid/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MprBr.png)

Answer (score 0):

Found the Solution about converting the GUID

https://github.com/IfcOpenShell/IfcOpenShell/blob/master/src/ifcopenshell-python/ifcopenshell/guid.py#L56

Comment: Do you know if this GUID will change across several imports/exports processes of the IFC file?

Comment: This depends on the software you use and how this software handles the GUIDs. In my case, i am using cadwork 3D, there is the GUID stored/kept. Except when I e.g. cut the element apart, then of course new GUID's are generated.